# Is there any global flag for Groovy static compilation?

Tags: groovy, static, compilation

I know that since Groovy 2.0 there are annotations for static compilation.
However it's ease to omit such annotation by accident and still run into troubles.

Is there any way to achieve the opposite compiler behaviour, like compile static all project files by default and compile dynamic only files chosen by purpose with some kind @CompileDynamic annotation for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not at this time, but there is an [open Jira issue here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5503) you can follow to watch progress for this feature

There was also a discussion about methods for doing this [on the Groovy developers list](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Type-checking-by-default-and-other-variants-td5710513.html)

Comment: Thanks, I have just voted up the JIRA issue and now am following it.

Comment: As @topr mentioned, this is now a feature in groovy 2.1+, it might be good to update the answer for future visitors.

Comment: Coo, thanks for info. I'll update the answer as soon as I have time to craft example of how to use this feature. Anybody is welcome to post till then though.

Answer (score 20):

I have found some (I believe recently introduced) feature which allows doing so with Gradle.

In *build.gradle* file for the project containing groovy sources we need to add following lines:

```
compileGroovy {
    configure(groovyOptions) {
        configurationScript = file("$rootDir/config/groovy/compiler-config.groovy")
    }
}
```

or `compileTestGroovy { ...` for applying the same to test sources. Keep in mind that neither static compilation nor type checking works well with Spock Framework though. Spock by its nature utilizes dynamic 'groovyness' a lot.

Then on a root of the project create folder *config/groovy/* and a file named *compiler-config.groovy* within. The content of the file is as follows:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

withConfig(configuration) {
    ast(CompileStatic)
}
```

Obviously path and name of the *configurationScript* may vary and it's up to you. It shouldn't rather go to the same *src/main/groovy* though as it would be mixing totally separate concerns.

The same may be done with `groovy.transform.TypeChecked` or any other annotation, of course.

To reverse applied behaviour on certain classes or methods then `@CompileDynamic` annotation or `@TypeChecked(TypeCheckingMode.SKIP)` respectively may be used.

I'm not sure how to achieve the same when no Gradle is in use as build tool. I may update this answer in the future with such info though.

Comment: Hey, Is this written somewhere in Groovy's docs? Can you provide the source for this solution?

Comment: I agree with @ThanosFisherman - I see no documentation or explanation of this feature. I looked at the code and it seems to point to [this block](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/6b6cc275db660a848f768d691b6a43b01bbe7e73/src/main/groovy/groovy/ui/GroovyMain.java#L307-L319) that runs the configurations.

Comment: @ThanosFisherman I think it's what's referred [at Groovy docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/tools-groovyc.html#section-groovyc-compiler) by `--configscript` switch.
I can't find docs describing syntax of the script itself though.

Comment: After looking a bit more, I think the source code for the compiler configuration can be found in [`CompilerCustomizationBuilder`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/ac0e1d232f0612518a87ce2aa5e443e0975cb3f4/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/control/customizers/builder/CompilerCustomizationBuilder.groovy).